# SUMIF to sum cells only if other corresponding cells contain a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to solve this:

[image]

I'm playing around with the `sumif` and `sumifs` function but I can't seem to figure it out.

It's important to sum up all cells of B only, and only if the corresponding cells A have a number in it (any number will do). This condition is important, because some cells are empty, some have random strings in it, some are marked with "N.A.", etc.

Comment: Are all column A numbers non-negative?

Comment: It's unfortunate that you've cross-posted this and not felt the need to let us know: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1095283-summif-all-cells-b-but-only-if-corresponding-cells-a-that-contain-numbers-in-it.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(A2:A8),B2:B8)
```

First create TRUE FALSE vector - `ISNUMBER`, then convert to 1,0 - `--`, then `SUMPRODUCT`.

[image]

Here is another way suggested at [Excel Forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1095283-summif-all-cells-b-but-only-if-corresponding-cells-a-that-contain-numbers-in-it.html):

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8,"<"&10^99,B2:B8)
```

Comment: This is fine, though SUMIF is more efficient and can take whole column references without detriment to performance.

Comment: @XORLX do you mind posting SUMIF solution, I presume you are suggesting a bit of a hack by checking if the cell is less than 0: `=SUMIF(A2:A8,">0",B2:B8)`

Comment: Not at all! Not sure it's a "hack", though! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the column A numbers are strictly non-negative:

`=SUMIF(A:A,">=0",B:B)`

If that column may contain negative numbers:

`=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,{">0","<"}&0,B:B))`

Note that any numbers stored as text in column A will not be considered, neither by these solutions nor that given by zx8754.

Regards